# How to handle button in dynamic list having same Text?

Tags: android

I am creating a dynamic list in which has 2 buttons (Accept and Reject) and one TextView (Email ID which is unique).

I have to accept/reject the email Id on button click event. My problem is I am not able to get the Id or any other reference to point which accept button i had clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign an ID to each button in your view.

Then create a separate OnClickListener for each button, each calling their own method?

If each item in your list has 2 buttons, search for the ID withing the parent container, then add the OnClickListener to the found button.

Comment: But the no of button is also dynamic so how can i set id to each button ?

Comment: Use setId(someButtonId). Or your could use getChildAt(someIndex) in the parent layout to find the button you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Create dynamic controll.You have to set some id for your controll

```
 ` ////////////Create weekdays button//////////////
              Button week_btn = new Button(this); 
              week_btn.setWidth(55);
              week_btn.setHeight(45);
              week_btn.setText("days"); 
              week_btn.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
              week_btn.setId(NEW_BTN_SELECT_DAYWEEK_id + i);
              cur_lin_layout.addView(week_btn, p);

              week_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                      current_period_id = v.getId() + 500;
                      lDayFlags = 0;
                      showDialog(0);
                  }
              });`
```

just create your own constant id and increase it after creating new controll(button). You set your controll and you can give it from click listner or finviewbyid